# WPF Polyline disk binary serialization

Tags: wpf, serialization, binary

In WPF I need to binary serialize a Polyline variable with a large number of points. I use the following code:

```
SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
sf.FileName = "Orig.txt"); 

if (sf.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(sf.FileName, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    try
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, plOriginal);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + exc.Message);
    }

    fs.Close();
}
```

but I get the error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'System.Windows.Media.PolyLineSegment' in Assembly 'PresentationCore,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is
>   not marked as serializable.    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph)    at
>   CurveAnalyzerDemoWPF.MainWindow.rbSave_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) in MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 92}

So any workaround to make it work?
thanx in advance

EDIT: I put the serializable attribute on the polyline variable:

```
[Serializable]
private PolyLineSegment plOriginal = new PolyLineSegment();
```

but I got the compilation following error:
 Error  1   Attribute 'Serializable' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, struct, enum, delegate' declarations.   F:\C# WPF\CurveAnalyzerDemoWPF\CurveAnalyzerDemoWPF\MainWindow.xaml.cs  55  4   CurveAnalyzerDemoWPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is quite self-explanatory. To use binary formater target class have to be marked with `[Serializable]` attribute. I suggest you to serialize data instead of 3rd party class instance.
You can create your own class with [Serialiable] attribute to store points coordinates, build up polylines from it and update it's data if needed. And then just serialize your own class.

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    PolyLineData dataStorage = new PolyLineData();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateFromXaml();
        SaveToFile();
        LoadFromFile();
        PopulateToXaml();
    }

    private void PopulateToXaml()
    {
        polyLine.Points = new PointCollection(dataStorage.Points);
    }

    public void SaveToFile()
    {
        SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
        sf.FileName = "Orig.txt";
        if (sf.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(sf.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            try
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, dataStorage);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + exc.Message);
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
    }

    public void LoadFromFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
        if ((bool)of.ShowDialog())
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(of.FileName, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            dataStorage = bf.Deserialize(fs) as PolyLineData;
            fs.Close();
        }
    }

    public void PopulateFromXaml()
    {
        foreach (var item in polyLine.Points)
        {
            dataStorage.Points.Add(item);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class PolyLineData
    {
        public List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Polyline Stroke="LightBlue" 
              StrokeThickness="4" 
              Name="polyLine"
              Points="10,150 30,140 50,170 70,120 90,190 110,100 130,210 150,80 170,230 190,60 210,250 230,150 320,150" />
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanx a million for your answer. As you can see in my edit I already tried to set the serializer attribute.  And it didn't work. Your solution is brilliant and I already thought about that but since I am dealing with 10^6 points. So it might be time-consuming (not that much though). So I'd prefer to find a workaround to mark it Serializable. Shouldn't I get to do that I'll follow your solution.

Comment: @Patrick this is because this attribute has to be set at class definition. Since PolyLine isn't the class you've made you are not able to do it easily.

Comment: Well, I don't think that this approach adds a lot of time for execution, but you can test it. You can try using 3rd party serializers. Some of them might work faster then binary finalizer.
By serializing PolyLine you will actually serialize all of its fields and properties. And it actually has 98 properties, since it's a WPF object

Comment: @Patrick bottom-line is: you should serialize data, not WPF System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline.

Comment: @nethaolic you'r right!! Serializing 10^6 point on hard disk on a I7 takes 2.5 seconds of which 40ms of data transfer and 1.96' of disk save. Could you suggest a good third party serializer?

Comment: Here http://geekswithblogs.net/LeonidGaneline/archive/2015/05/06/serializers-in-.net.-v.2.aspx is good article on .net serializers. Accept my answer please, if you find it helpfull